# How do I test whether there's a file-syncing program running?

Tags: windows, delphi, google-drive-api, dropbox, vcl

Does anyone know how to test in Delphi/VCL to see if Dropbox (or similar cloud syncing tools such as Google Drive, MS One-Drive, etc.) are:

1. running on a client computer, and
2. whether they are set to synchronize a particular folder/directory?

I am asking because I have been having issues with the database I am using (NexusDB).  When the program database is installed in a folder that is also being synchronized by Dropbox this seems to cause program crashes (Dropbox seems to temporarily lock files making them unavailable to my program).  I would like to be able to test for this and at least warn users.

I notice by the way that TMS software has a set of Delphi components for working with cloud syncing software, but have not tried these yet.

Comment: Have you considered making your program resilient to temporarily locked files? That seems like the more user-friendly solution.

Comment: No - good idea - any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: On second thoughts I think this would probably be impractical, since I use a database tool that is continually opening and closing tables.

Comment: If the database tool is closing the table, I would assume it's so that *others* can open it. (Otherwise, why not just keep it open exclusively all the time?) But now you think you've determined that when others *do* open it, the database tool fails? This seems like a shortcoming you should talk to your database-tool vendor about.

Comment: A suggestion would be to move the files from the Dropbox folder, and instead, periodically upload them to Dropbox from your application using TMS Dropbox components or other..

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Just to be clear my software is a single user application and I am not specially interested in having things sync with Dropbox.  Its just that some of the users of my program tend to use Dropbox to sync all of their My Documents folders, one of which contains the data for the software.  I don't have any control of whether or not they use Dropbox (or soemthing similar).